# Adding a 0 before digit in an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help when you enter a single digit month in a date of birth that will automatically add a 0 digit in a single digit in an input.Here's my code:

```
    $('#dob_dd').blur(function(){
       var addzero = $('#dob_dd').val().length;
      if (addzero.length != 2) {
            addzero = '0' + addzero; 
      } else {
        return addzero;
    }
});
```

Comment: I just tested this logic in the Chrome JS console and it appears to work.  What then is the actual problem?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Calling length on an integer seems weird to me, nor does it actually change the value.

Comment: Didn't know `val()` returns int (I'm not a UI person).  Sorry.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It doesn't, but calling length on the value does.

Answer (score 0):

You already specify that you want to check the length of `$('#dob_dd')`. So maybe it should be :

```
if (addzero != 2)
```

Then of course you need to update the value using for instance `$('#dob_dd').val("new value")`

Comment: okay what if multiple inputs how can you add in your condition?

Comment: @Jemai Create a generic function to pass to the handler setup. You might want to operate on classes rather than IDs though.

Comment: @Jemai - as your selector is an ID, there can not be multiple inputs targetted by this anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the displayed value. it's as simple as

```
$('#dob_dd').blur(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.value(('0' + $this.value()).substr(-2));
});
```

This will function correctly if the selector selects multiple targets as well